# Errores al compilar codeblocks c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy intentando compilar este codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int checkfile(char *argv[0]);
void bind();
void play();

int main(int argn, char *argv[])
{
    if(checkfile(argv)==1)
        bind();
    else
        play();

    return 0;
}

int checkfile(char *argv[0])
{
    FILE *fp;

    int i;
    char *content;

    unsigned long size;

    fp=fopen(argv[0], "rb");

    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    size=ftell(fp);

    rewind(fp);
    content=(char *)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    fread(content, size, 1, fp);

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        if(content[i]=='*' && content[i+1]=='*' && content[i+2] == '*') {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}

void bind()
{
    char file1[]="hello1.exe";
    char file2[]="hello2.exe";
    char file3[]="hellobinded.exe";

    char *content1;
    char *content2;

    char separator[]={ '*', '*', '*' };

    unsigned long size1;
    unsigned long size2;

    FILE *fp;

    if((fp=fopen(file1, "rb"))==NULL) { return; }

    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    size1=ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    content1=(char *)malloc(size1*sizeof(char));

    fread(content1, size1, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    if((fp=fopen(file2, "rb"))==NULL) { return; }

    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    size2=ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    content2=(char *)malloc(size2*sizeof(char));

    fread(content2, size2, 1, fp);

    CopyFile("binder.exe", file3, FALSE);

    if((fp=fopen(file3, "ab"))==NULL) {  return; }

    fwrite(separator, strlen(separator), 1, fp);
    fwrite(content1, size1, 1, fp);
    fwrite(separator, strlen(separator), 1, fp);
    fwrite(content2, size2, 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}

void play()
{
    FILE *fp;

    char file1[]="hellobinded.exe";
    char file2[]="new1.exe";
    char file3[]="new2.exe";
    char *content;

    int i, j;

    unsigned long sobra;
    unsigned long filesize;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long size1;

    if((fp=fopen(file1, "rb"))==NULL) { return;}

    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    size=ftell(fp);

    rewind(fp);
    content=(char *)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    fread(content, size, 1, fp);

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        if(content[i]=='*' && content[i+1]=='*' && content[i+2] == '*') {
            sobra=i+3;
            break;
        }

    for(j=i+6; j<size; j++)
        if(content[j]=='*' && content[j+1]=='*' && content[j+2] == '*') {
            filesize=j-i;
            break;
        }

    size1=sobra+filesize;

    fclose(fp);

    if((fp=fopen(file2, "wb+"))==NULL) { return; }

    for(i=sobra+3; i<size1; i++)
        fputc(content[i], fp);

    fclose(fp);

    if((fp=fopen(file3, "wb+"))==NULL) { return; }

    for(i=j+6; i<size; i++)
        fputc(content[i], fp);

    fclose(fp);


}
```

Pero me da los siguientes errores:

> ||=== Build: Debug in Example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\user\Example\main.c|6|error: conflicting types for 'bind'|
>   C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\winsock2.h|537|note:
>   previous declaration of 'bind' was here|
>   C:\Users\user\Example\main.c|47|error: conflicting types for 'bind'|
>   C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\winsock2.h|537|note:
>   previous declaration of 'bind' was here| ||=== Build failed: 2
>   error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 9 second(s)) ===|

Puede ser el compilador estoy haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` es un nombre ya utilizado por winsock2. Lo que sucede es que se está produciendo una colisión con los nombres.

Cambia el nombre de tu función o insértala en un espacio de nombres para evitar la colisión:

```
namespace MisFunciones
{
  void bind()
  { ... }
} 

int main()
{
  // ...
  MisFunciones::bind();
  // ...
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Una cosa. las MAUSCULAS y las minusculas se diferencian, asi que la puedes llamar `BIND` o `Bind` y no tendras problemas.

Comment: Seguro que sí, pero la legibilidad del programa se puede resentir mucho si llamar a una función u otra depende exclusivamente de la combinación concreta de mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: ¿pero no pasaria lo mismo con el `namespace`?

Comment: @bassily si eres de los que disfruta poniendo `using namespace` por todos lados sí. Si en cambio evitas esa práctica y únicamente importas los espacios de nombre cuando realmente suponen una traba para la lectura del código...